# Multiple security configurations in conflict

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have implemented several security configurations, the first one I need basic auth under the endpoint (`test1`).

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AdminServiceImpl adminService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("/api/${smartwatcher.api-prefix}")
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, apiPrefix + "/test1").authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(adminService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(adminService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
```

Second one, endpoints are accesible after auth with session token. Join together, second config does not work properly, it looks like a authentication issue. Alone, working perfect. Any idea?

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Value("/api/${smartwatcher.api-prefix}")
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(apiPrefix + "/test2", apiPrefix + "/test3")
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(new AdminSessionTokenFilter(adminService), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, apiPrefix + "/test2").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, apiPrefix + "/test3").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: more or less solved.. my question is , is there anyway to send Basic auth credentials encrypted? very risky sending them as text/plain

Comment: No, it isn't risky. You should always use HTTPS, so your communcation is encrypted.